# Do South Africans require any sort of visa for a 5 hour stop over in Abu Dhabi?

Tags: transit, uae, south-african-citizens, auh

I have a 5 hour wait for my connecting flight in Abu Dhabi and was wondering whether I require any sort of visa.

I have no intention of leaving the airport and I am a South African citizen. I am flying from Sydney to Abu Dhabi and then on to Johannesburg.

Answer (score 2):

**No, you won't need a transit visa,** since your layover is under 24 hours.

> National South Africa (ZA)
>   Transit United Arab Emirates (AE)
>   Destination South Africa (ZA)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

Source: [TIMATIC](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=ZA&TR=AUH&DE=JNB&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)